# Get absolute (index) position of cursor in Monaco Editor

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I am retrieving text as string from editor and want to insert some marker text `_CURSOR_` to position of cursor.

Here is the code:

```js
let editor = /* ... */;

// Getting text
let text = editor.getValue();

// Getting cursor position
let indexPos = editor./* ??? */

// Adding text
text = text.substring(0, pos) + '_CURSOR_' + text.substring(pos);
```

How do I get the absolute position of cursor in resulting string? `getPosition()` returns an object containing `line` and `column` values but I can't use them to insert my marker text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an absolute (index) position of cursor in text by combining `getOffsetAt` with `getPosition` methods.

```
let indexPos = editor.getModel().getOffsetAt(editor.getPosition());
```